# How to update a MySQL table field where 2 columns match (email) but another set of columns (member ID) are not synchronized

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I've searched through a ton of these Stack Overflow questions and I'm having trouble getting sorted on this. The biggest problem I have is the queries I've found and tried are timing out (20,000 records in the member table and the wp_users table). I'm not super advanced with MySQL so I'm sure there must be a way to do it properly but I haven't yet figured it out.

I have a wordpress user table and a very dated member plugin table.
wp_users: ID, user_email
members: member_id, email

I'm trying to compare the ID, user_email field to this member plugin table that has member_id, email. The email in both tables should match but the ID / member_id may not.

My goal is to perform an UPDATE to change the member_id of all users in that member table to match the ID in the wp_users table where the emails match between both tables, but most everything I've found and tried times out.

---

Here is an example of a select query I tried to use to update, but like a lot of the other things I tried it just times out after 600 seconds.

```
UPDATE IGNORE members_tbl AS eMember JOIN wp_users AS u ON eMember.email = u.user_email SET eMember.member_id = u.ID WHERE eMember.member_id != u.ID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you have should work just fine.  The problem is likely that you do not have an index on these tables on the email.  There is no getting around doing the join on that email, but joins on non-indexed columns are supremely inefficient.  I would add an index on the email column on both tables.

Comment: that's a basic rule-of-thumb for dbs: any field(s) used in a decision context (where, join, order-by, having, etc...) should have an index on them.

Comment: I did a search about adding indexes and I indexed the email on both tables, the same query that timed-out in 600 seconds, completed in 1.2611. Thank you sir.